# Issue in using securesocial-master SNAPSHOT jar with play activator application that uses jdk 1.6 for compilation

Tags: playframework-2.0, securesocial

I am using `securesocial_2.11-master-SNAPSHOT.jar` in my play application. Earlier my application compiled successfully using jdk1.7. Now I have to use jdk1.6 in my application. So while compiling application using "activator compile" command getting below Error. It seems that securesocial-master is compiled with jdk1.7.

How can I use securesocial-master jar in play application that uses jdk1.6?

```
[warn] Error reading API from class file : java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionErro
r: securesocial/core/java/BaseUserService : Unsupported major.minor version 51.0

java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: securesocial/core/java/SecuredAction : U
nsupported major.minor version 51.0
at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClassCond(ClassLoader.java:631)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:615)
at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:14
```

Comment: Why do you need to use jdk 6? I am asking because it officially reached end-of-life a [while back](https://blogs.oracle.com/henrik/entry/java_6_eol_h_h)

Comment: It's because other components in my application has been written in JDK 6. Any how issue is resolved after changing play & sbt plugin version from 2.3.5 to 2.3.2

Comment: I recently compiled master with target 1.6.